# Is it a bad idea to navigate in a custom hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to make a custom fetch hook to help me handle some http error in general. When the response.status is 401, then navigate to the main page.

```
const useFetch = (url, fetchOpts) => {
  // reducer here.....

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(fetchReducer, initialState);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!url) return;

    cancelRequest.current = false;

    const fetchData = async () => {
      dispatch({ type: 'loading' });

      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, fetchOpts);
        if (!response.ok) {
          if (response.status === 401) return navigate('/');
          }

        const data = await response.json();

        if (cancelRequest.current) return;

        dispatch({ type: 'fetched', payload: data });
      } catch (error) {
        if (cancelRequest.current) return;

        dispatch({ type: 'error', payload: error });
      }
    };

    fetchData();

    return () => {
      cancelRequest.current = true;
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [url]);

  return state;
};
```

although It's work, but I'm wondering is it alright if I just leave my previous component and not handle the rest of it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that separate your function **useFetch** will be a better approach.

**Why ?**

In computer science there is a design pattern called [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), in simple words this design pattern tells us we need to separate our functions into small ones that do only one thing.

My advice to you is to make your function **useFetch** return status, and make another function that checks if the status is **401** then you navigate the user to the main page

Comment: I think what you **mean** to say is that how an error is handled might be abstracted better. It wouldn’t make sense to handle the 401 in every component that uses the hook if they all handle it the same way.

Comment: yes, i mean the error handling should be abstracted, and make another function that handle the navigation itself. thank you for your remark.